# How do we interpret the group structure of the ideal class group?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given a number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$, let $\text{Cl}(K)$ denote the ideal class group of $K$.

My question is: how do we interpret the *group structure* of $\text{Cl}(K)$? To be clear, I understand how to interpret the *order* of the class group: if the class group of $K$ has order $1$, then the number ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ has unique factorization; if the class group has order bigger than $1$, then $\mathcal{O}_K$ doesn't have unique factorization. But that is only part of the picture: what if you have two number fields whose class groups have the same order, but different group structures? (Say, for example: a class group of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ versus a class group of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.) What is an intuitive way to interpret this difference? Does it have any meaning?

I have some vague sense that the structure of $\text{Cl}(K)$ measures "the complexity of the arithmetic" in the number ring, but I don't really know what that means. Any of your insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since you did not bring it up, how do you interpret multiplication of nonzero ideals in $\mathcal O_K$? That is an operation that leads to the group law on ideal classes in the class group. By the way, your comment on the order of the class group is not really an understanding of the order itself, but only the weaker dichotomy “order is $1$” vs. “order is not $1$”. Ultimately not everything is going to have an intuitive meaning (like the 37th homology group of a topological space).

Comment: first of all it is an abelian finite group so the group law does not mean much, the important thing is the order of elements, for example the difference between two thing you consider is that in one square of any ideal is principal while in the other this is not true

Comment: of course in the function field case the multiplication has a geometric meaning and appear naturally in the riemann roch theorem and etc

Comment: Multiplying *principal* ideals is like multiplying numbers together. But nonprincipal ideals are more subtle, especially the phenomenon of two nonprincipal ideals having a product that is principal. Nonprincipal ideal classes are a kind of twistedness. For example, $\mathbf R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is a Dedekind domain with an ideal class of order $2$ and its ideal classes correspond to the two vector bundles on the circle (cylinder and Moebius strip). Two ideals in a Dedekind domain $A$ are in the same ideal class if and only if they are isomorphic $A$-modules.

Comment: @KCd That's a very nice geometric interpretation of the ideal class group! Is there a book you'd recommend which elaborates on this connection between ideal class groups and vector bundles? I'd love to learn more about it.

Comment: The relation is between projective modules and vector bundles, by work of Serre and Swan (google "serre swan projective").  Each nonzero ideal in a Dedekind domain $R$ is a projective $R$-module. Are you talking with professors at your school about these questions you are asking?

Comment: The ideal class group question yes! About Serre-Swan, not at the moment; that was just something that struck me as interesting when you had mentioned it. :)

Comment: It struck me as interesting too!

Answer (score 3):

When the class group consists only of cycles having order 2, like the Klein four-group, then we can profitably augment the ring with "square-root" elements and then turn a nonunique factorization into a unique one with the square roots.

To illustrate, consider the number $66$ as it factors in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ and in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-30}]$, both of which have class number $4$:

$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]: 66=2×3×11=2×(4+\sqrt{-17})(4-\sqrt{-17})=(7+\sqrt{-17})(7-\sqrt{-17})$

$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-30}]: 66=2×3×11=(6+\sqrt{-30})(6-\sqrt{-30})$

I now claim that in the latter case, where the class group is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z×\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ rather than $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, I can use square-root augmentation to render a unique factorization of $66$, from which the two factorizations $2×3×11$ and $(6+\sqrt{-30})(6-\sqrt{-30})$ can both be derived.

The number $1+2\sqrt{-30}$ has a perfect square Euclidean norm, but we can't reduce it in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-30}]$ per se. But, if we bring elements of the form $a\sqrt{6}+b\sqrt{-5}$, then we can render

$1+2\sqrt{-30}=(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{-5})^2.$

Similarly, using two other square root extensions with integer radicands, we have

$7+2\sqrt{-30}=(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{-3})^2,$

$13+2\sqrt{-30}=(\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{-2})^2.$

These then represent the square-root augmentation of the Klein four-group class domain $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-30}]$ with which a number like $66$ may be uniquely factored. To wit, using all three of the square root extensions:

$66 = (\sqrt{-2})^2(\sqrt{-3})^2(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{-5})(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{-5}).$

And from this one augmented-domain factorization, allowing also the unit factor $-1$, we get both:

$66=[(-1)(\sqrt{-2})^2][(-1)(\sqrt{-3})^2][(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{-5})(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{-5})]=2×3×11$

$66=[(-1)\sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-3}(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{-5})][(-1)\sqrt{-2}\sqrt{-3}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{-5})]=(6+\sqrt{-30})(6-\sqrt{-30}).$

None of this works with $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ where the class group $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ has a cycle of order greater than $2$, at least not using square roots. We can identify a square root of (let us say) $\pm(8+\sqrt{-17})$, but its terms will not augment the domain in a way that maps both $2×3×11$,$2×(4+\sqrt{-17})(4-\sqrt{-17})$ and $(7+\sqrt{-17})(7-\sqrt{-17})$ into a unique factorization of $66$.